# How to add cursor pointer and other css to material ui datepicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My Material UI datepicker component in React is not showing the cursor and also the icon I added is not clickable and does not show the datepicker dialog.

I've tried inline styling/styled-components but couldn't do it.

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
        <DatePicker
            readOnly
            ref='datepicker'
            labelFunc={this.formatWeekSelectLabel}
            // value=""
            onChange={this.handleDateChange}
            animateYearScrolling
            InputProps={{
                disableUnderline: true,
            }}      
        />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

What happens is that whatever within the black border of the component is clickable but does not show mouse pointer. Also the icon I put inside it is not clickable and does not make the dialog to appear.

Comment: Which versions of material-ui and material-ui pickers are you using? I could not find the `readOnly` prop in any of the current versions, but if it's implemented in the version you're using and giving your component read-only mechanics, maybe that is why you cannot interact with it (i.e. no cursor and no button interaction)?

Comment: "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^2.2.4", no. the readOnly has no affect and isnt the root problem

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me

```
const StyledKeyboardDatePicker = styled(KeyboardDatePicker)`
    & * {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
`;
```

you dont have to use the styled components you can just pass a style property with similar css rules.